# An ideal product with a non zero-divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a regular domain of finite type over a field. Let $I\subset A$ be an ideal and $f\in A$ be a non zero-divisor. We assume that $f\notin \sqrt{I}$, and every minimal prime ideal of $I$ has height one. Then it is always true that $I\cdot (f)=I\cap (f)$?

It is easy to see that $I\cdot (f)\subset I\cap (f)$. Now for an element $t\in I\cap (f)$, by the definition of $(f)$ we can write $t=a\cdot f$ for some $a\in A$. When $I+(f)=(1)$, i.e. $I$ and $(f)$ are coprime, we know that this is true. But I don't know how to show that we can always choose such $a$ in $I$ in general.

I'm wondering if this statement is true, or if there is a counter-example?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @LostinSpace Sorry, I add something I have thought about in the question.

Comment: Can you add some examples at least to guess initially whether it is true or not?

Comment: @LostinSpace Sure, for example, the coprime case.

Comment: Now your question looks more promising.

Comment: Since $A$ is an integral domain, $f$ being a non-zero-divisor just means that it is nonzero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $A=k[x,y]$, $I=(xy)$, and $f=x$. Then $I$ is radical, $f\notin I$, but $I\cdot(f)=(x^2y)$ while $I\cap(f)=(xy)$.

In general, you are looking for $V(I)$ and $V(f)$ to intersect in the expected dimension, i.e. $\dim V(I)-1$. See [here on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49259/when-is-the-product-of-two-ideals-equal-to-their-intersection) for more details.